# In parsing theory, what is the opposite of "derive"?

Tags: parsing, terminology, compiler-theory

Suppose you have a grammar such as this:

`S` → `A`

`A` → `E` "=" `E`

In this example, `S` *derives* the sequence (`E` "=" `E`). However, what is the opposite of this? That is, what is an appropriate word to fill in the blank:

"The sequence (`E` "=" `E`) ***_*__*_*__** `S`."

If we were to borrow the antonym from calculus, one could say that (`E` "=" `E`) *integrates* `S`, but that doesn't *seem* right.

Comment: Perhaps sequence composes `S`?

Comment: @Mikhail: Make that an answer and I will at least up-vote it. :)

Comment: @Jim: Another good suggestion! Like I recommended to Mikhail, you should also post this as an answer and I will up-vote it!

Comment: @Adam: But I'm not sure the answer is correct.  And the Wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar, doesn't help much.

Comment: If you're teaching a course, I'd say making a distinction between derivation and the opposite is useful but not essential. "Derive S" would make sense, but "Derive E=E" would not.

Comment: @Mikhail: Good call, even though I'm not teaching a course. This is all just for a pet project (one of many) I'm working on.

Comment: If you make millions on this pet project I want half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is, strictly speaking, such an antonym. Instead, they are both referred to as derivation. More specifically, what you describe in the question is called **"top-down" parsing**, whereas the reverse is known as **"bottom-up" parsing**.

In contrast to top-down parsing, wherein parsing begins from the start symbol and applies derivations until the entire input string is determined, bottom-up parsing starts from the input string and uses derivations in the opposite direction, stopping when it ultimately derives the starting symbol.

Also see: http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node12.html

However, I have seen the opposite of derivation referred to as **reduction**. Perhaps that's the term that you were thinking of?

(So maybe that formal logic course I took in college was finally good for something after all?)

Comment: +1: Seems like the most reasonable answer. It certainly makes a lot more sense this way. It's odd where those old courses will come in handy! :)

Comment: In bottom up parsing, the action of converting a sequence of already-seen language elements into a nonterminal is called a "reduction".  There's usually a piece of machinery associated it with that physically removes the "left hand side items" from a seen-history (usually a stack) and replaces it with the nonterminal.

Comment: @Ira: Thanks for the input. I was wondering if you would show up. :) What were you doing on Stack Overflow at 4 AM? By the way, I was watching some more of your talks. Very fascinating!